# Easier way to combine Indirect, Address and Row/Column functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with the columns:

| Param1 | Param2 | Param3 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Criteria |

This sheet has a command button to sort values by ascending Param1, Param2 and Param3. The button is already created and working.

There is another excel sheet where all column headers are the same except for Criteria, which doesn't exist. Here, Param columns are the same, while Value columns need to undergo a certain calculation (i.e. Value/100) if the value in Criteria column is not 0.

The formula for sheet2, D2 is:

=IF(Sheet1!$G2=0,Sheet1!D2,Sheet1!D2/100)

The formula for sheet2, A2 is:

=Sheet1!A2

However, when Sheet1 is sorted, Sheet2 contents don't get sorted automatically. For this, I thought I would need a more generic way to retrieve values from Sheet1.

The formula for sheet2, A2 would need to change to:

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,"Sheet1")), which copies the contents of Sheet1, row by row. The exact same formula is valid across columns A to C.

My main problem is, converting the formula for Sheet2, D2 using the functions above would turn into a very complex-looking formula:

=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),7,1,1,"Sheet1")) =0,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,"Sheet1")),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,"Sheet1"))/100)

Is there any way to achieve the same more smoothly?

Thank you.

Comment: Your assertion _However, when Sheet1 is sorted, Sheet2 contents don't get sorted automatically_ does not seem to be true.  After a sort of `Sheet1` using the Excel built in Sort the formula in `Sheet2!A2` remains as `=Sheet1!A2`, so returns the now first sorted value.  The list in `Sheet2` reflects the sorted data in `Sheet1`.  If the code behind your Sort button moves the cells, then change that code to move values, not cells.

Comment: I changed the code to, what I assume, the correct one, and now it seems to work flawlessly. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.